# How to determine Acrobat Reader version?

Tags: c#, windows, acrobat, dde

I need to determine Adobe Acrobat Reader version to use DDE connect string name.

In 10.0 release, Adobe change "DDE naming convention — the DDE server name has been made unique for Acrobat and for Reader. The new naming convention is as follows:
Acroview{A|R}{MajorVersion} where {A|R} refer to Acrobat and Reader respectively."

Is any information in registry ?

more info:
http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2011/01/big-changes-in-the-dde-naming-convention-for-acrobat-x.html

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the registry keys below `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe` - they provide among other things what SW is installed and the versions...

Answer (score 0):

You can find explanation on this side: [explanation](http://www.itsecdb.com/oval/objectdetails/oval/org.mitre.oval/obj/15547/windows-registry_object-Registry-key-holds-Adobe-Reader-10-Series-DisplayVersion-32/).

```
var guid = ... //get guid from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\Installer : ENU_GUID
var key = RegistryTool.GetKey(Registry.LocalMachine, "SOFTWARE|Microsoft|Windows|CurrentVersion|Uninstall|" + guid); // my registry tool implementation
string adobeVersion = key.GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString();
```